# One element is floating up,

Tags: html, css

In my header, the Signup button is floating slightly up compared to the the other elements. I used no command for which it is floating slightly upper. It does not matter if the signup button is the 1st/2nd/3rd/4th element, it is slightly upper anyhow.

[image]

How can I take it to the exact place like other elements?

**html**

```
<header>
  <button id="myBtn"><b>Login</b></button>
   <form action="signupform.php">
     <button><b> Signup </b></button>
   </form>
  <a href="#"><img src="logo/android.png" width="25px" height="25px"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="logo/apple.png" width="25px" height="25px"></a>
</header>
```

**css**

```
header{
  border: 1px white solid;
  /*border-bottom-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.35);*/
  max-width: 960px;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  /* text-align: center; */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  z-index: 999;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

header a {
  display: flex;
}

header img {
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your form element is not having the `margin: auto;` style. Try adding it inside your `header img` with a comma seperation. Something like this

```
 header img,
 header form {
    margin: auto;
 }
```

**Sample [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5afeu3p9/)**

Answer (score 0):

This is because your button is inside the form tag. Form doesn't know that it is in a grid layout. Add this style for form tag

```
form{ display: grid }
```

This fits your form into a grid layout

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<header>
   <button id="myBtn"><b>Login</b></button>
   <form action="signupform.php">
      <button><b> Signup </b></button>
   </form>
   <a href="#"><img src="logo/android.png" width="25px" height="25px" /></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="logo/apple.png" width="25px" height="25px" /></a>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
    border: 1px white solid;
    /*border-bottom-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.35);*/
    max-width: 960px;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    /* text-align: center; */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 50px;
    grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    z-index: 999;
    justify-content: space-around;
 }

 header a {
    display: flex;
 }

 header form {
    display: flex;
 }

 header img {
    margin: auto;
 }
```